# R selenium select all elements with css like _1, _2

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I would like to dowload all the emails from this [website](http://peoplefinder.tcd.ie/#DEPTSEARCHRESULT).
I figured out that to do that I should select each name in "department listing" and then click to open the masked names. How can I select the complete list of emails? For example to do it on "Anatomy" I am trying the following.

Moreover, is there a better way to select all departments css selectors first and then looping on them to get the emails?
Thanks in advance

```
library(RSelenium)

dep<-"http://peoplefinder.tcd.ie/#DEPTSEARCHRESULT" #my url

#open connection
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(dep)
#find and click on "Anatomy"
  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#MainContent_UserControlSearchForPerson_DropDownListDepartments > option:nth-child(9)')  
  webElem$clickElement()
#open masked list
  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#DEPTSEARCHRESULT > div.panel-heading > div.panel-title.visible-md.visible-lg > h4 > a')  # this matches for the element which is interactable
  webElem$clickElement()
  #now I cannot get the right css if I substite _# with _1 for example I get the first element but I would like the full list
  text<-remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', 'MainContent_UserControlSearchForPerson_RepeaterSubDeptParent_RepeaterSubDeptChild_0_UserControlEmailAddress_#_EmailLink_#')$getElementText()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved in this way; Is there a better/faster possible code in your opinion?

```
dep<-"http://peoplefinder.tcd.ie/#DEPTSEARCHRESULT"


rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
#MainContent_UserControlSearchForPerson_DropDownListDepartments > option:nth-child(8)-(225)
toclick<-paste0('#MainContent_UserControlSearchForPerson_DropDownListDepartments > option:nth-child(', 8:225, ')')
mail<-list()
for(i in 1:length(toclick)){
remDr$navigate(dep)

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', toclick[i])  # click on items in dropdown menu
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(3) #time to load the page


r<-webElem$getPageSource() #get all webpage text and selct mailto
r<-unlist(str_split(as.character(r),'"'))
w<-which(grepl("mailto:", r))
a<-r[w]
a<-gsub("mailto:", "", a, fixed = T)
a<-gsub("%40", "@", a, fixed = T)
a<-unique(a)

mail<-c(mail,a)

}
```